# Functional Programming: Having a very difficult time understanding how this function lazily evaluates

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm working through the `Functional Programming in Scala` book, and am on the section about lazy evaluation.  There is an exercise to implement a `takeWhile` function using `foldRight`.  I was able to complete it successfully, but when I added print statements I saw that it seems to be doing processing I wouldn't expect.  I am very confused by this.

Here is the code:

```
trait McStream[+A] {
    def uncons: Option[(A, McStream[A])]

    def isEmpty: Boolean = uncons.isEmpty

    def toList: List[A] = {
      uncons match {
        case Some(head -> tail) => head :: tail.toList
        case None => Nil
      }
    }

    def foldRight[B](z: => B)(f: (A, => B) => B): B = {
      uncons match {
        case Some(head -> tail) =>
          println(s"Inside foldRight, head is $head")
          f(head, tail.foldRight(z)(f))
        case None => z
      }
    }

    // TODO how does evaluate?  Trace steps
    // TODO it seems to be storing a deferred takeWhile in the `b` variable that evaluates during the cons
    def takeWhile(p: A => Boolean): McStream[A] = {
      foldRight(McStream.empty[A]) { (a, b) =>
        println(s"a is $a, b is $b")
        if (p(a)) {
          McStream.cons(a, b)
        } else {
          McStream.empty
        }
      }
    }
}
```

With a helper object for constructors:

```
object McStream {
    def empty[A]: McStream[A] = new McStream[A] {
      override def uncons: Option[(A, McStream[A])] = None
    }

    def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => McStream[A]): McStream[A] = {
      new McStream[A] {
        lazy val uncons = Some((hd, tl))
      }
    }

    def apply[A](as: A*): McStream[A] = {
      if (as.isEmpty) empty
      else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the test I'm running:

```
"take while a predicate is matched" in {
      val stream = McStream(1, 2)
      stream.takeWhile(_ < 2).toList shouldEqual List(1)
    }
```

And here is the output I get:

```
Inside foldRight, head is 1
Inside foldRight, head is 2
a is 2, b is McStream(None)
a is 1, b is McStream(None)
Inside foldRight, head is 2
a is 2, b is McStream(None)
```

I'm confused about the last two lines, to me it seems like it should recurse all the way to the end of the list, and then either connect the currently processed tail to the next element if the predicate matches, or replace it with an empty `McStream` otherwise.  At that point, it should just be returning the list, and not doing the additional `foldRight` and evaluation.

Here is the evaluation order as far as I can understand it:

```
Stream(1, Stream(2, Stream.empty)).takeWhile(_ < 2)
should print Inside foldRight, head is 1
Stream(2, Stream.empty).takeWhile(_ < 2)
should print Inside foldRight, head is 2
Stream.empty.takeWhile(_ < 2)
End of recursion, starts to return
Stream(2, Stream.empty).takeWhile(_ < 2)
should print a is 2, b is Stream.empty
Stream(1, Stream.empty).takeWhile(_ < 2)
should print a is 1, b is Stream.empty
1 #:: Stream.empty
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the very mechanisms I was using to try to understand the evaluation (`println` statements), were forcing evaluation and causing the above issues.  When I remove the print statements it evaluates like it should.

Don't use `println` in your lazy evaluations!